# Running Program in Hebrew with Wine

Tags: fonts, hebrew, wine

I Have a program that when i try to run in Hebrew - the characters display as lines and boxes - i downloaded a Hebrew font and put it into the font folder in windows and tried to use the name of the font when opening the file eg. LANG he_IL.font-name pgm name - but it keeps showing me boxes
I am not fluent in techy-terms so detailed guidance is most appreciated

Comment: Help us help you.  Which program?  Which version?  What is your environment?  The more details you give, the more serious your question looks.

Comment: my version of Ubuntu 14.04 of wine - 1.7.44   On the file properties under"Command" it says {env WINEPREFIX="/home/yehoshua/.wine" wine C:\\DBS\\TaklitorTorani.Exe } and the location is /home/yehoshua/Desktop.  and the error i get is fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
Looking forward to some insights

Comment: edit your question with the information in the comments, and add line breaks and formatting as needed.  The more you invest in your question, the more others will invest in their answers.

Comment: Try to install [Tahoma Font](http://download.microsoft.com/download/office97pro/fonts/1/w95/en-us/tahoma32.exe) this solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - but already tried that